# Spring cloud contract regex(nonBlank()) generates control symbols

Tags: java, groovy, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

Why does regex(nonBlank()) in spring cloud contracts sometimes generate control symbols like \u0008, which break compilation of generated java files? This makes nonBlank() kind of unreliable and not-usable. I can specify own regex like `[a-z]*` , but it would be handy to also cover non ascii unicode symbols.

Example contract:

```
package contracts.api
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract
Contract.make {
  request {
    method 'GET'
    urlPath('/v1/users') {
      queryParameters {
        parameter 'userId': value(regex(nonBlank()))
      }
    }
  }
  response {
    status 200
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass only the regular expression, Spring Cloud Contract uses a library called Xeger to generate a concrete value that matches that regular expression. Sometimes it generates such values.

So IMO in such cases, it's better to use `$(anyNonBlankString())` (instead of `value(regex(nonBlank()))`) where we set a fixed value of a String (and e.g. add a random number to it) instead of generating it from regex.

Comment: Reason for nonBlank() was it generated unicode symbols like 漢字 and i need to ensure that API realization handles them OK. (e.g. in user names). anyNonBlankString() uses A-Z character set as i see. I could use my own check string with any special characters I expect, but then I'll have to copy-paste this pattern which i wish to avoid.

Comment: Can you file an issue in sc contract? Maybe i should ensure that the generated valieis escaped  properly

Comment: sure, created here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/521, thank you